# Java:Calling method, initialized in one class, gives Nullpointerexception in other class

Tags: java, instance, public, public-method

I defined a Logininfo class to store the email and password of a user in. I get the email and password from a Login GUI. There are put into the Logininfo class using setMethods. I'm connecting the programming to a mysql server (mysql is not an issue here). I need the the emailadres and password so I can use it for queries in other GUI's later on.

This is the Logininfo class

```
public class Logininfo {

public static Emailadres emailadres = new Emailadres();
public static Password password = new Password();

public static class Emailadres
{
    private String emailadres;

    public Emailadres()
    {
        emailadres = " ";
    }

    public void setEmailadres(String emailadres)
    {
        this.emailadres = emailadres;
    }

    public String getEmailadres()
    {
        return(emailadres);
    }

}

public static class Password
{

    private String password ;

    public Password()
    {
        password = " ";
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return(password);
    }

}

}
```

In the login GUI I use the setMethod to store the emailadress and password.

```
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Logininfo logininfo;
    Logininfo.Emailadres emailadres = new Logininfo.Emailadres();
    Logininfo.Password password = new Logininfo.Password();

    private boolean validate_login(String email,String wachtwoord) {

    emailadres.setEmailadres(email);
    wachtwoord.setPassword(password);
```

Later on I try to retrieve the emailadress and password in another class.

```
public class Account extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Logininfo logininfo;
Logininfo.EmailAdres emailadres;
Logininfo.WachtWoord password;

emailadres.getEmailadres(email);
password.getPassword(password);
```

I get a Nullpointerexception here. I know that you have to make a new instance of Logininfo in the Login GUI screen. However in the Account class you can't make another new instance. Are public class not supposed to be used for this and should I use something else?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It seems that you are just learning Java. I *highly* recommend reading [a tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) first before embarking on a bigger adventure. For instance, did you know all objects need to explicitly allocated, unlike in C++?

Comment: When you set the email and password, the methods require a String type (the methods `setEmailadres(String)` and `setPassword(String)`). Where are defined `email` and `password`?

Comment: They are in a boolean to validate the login from mysql. I forgot to put the boolean in there. It is in there now.

Answer (score 0):

`email_adres` in your `Login` class is an instance field of that class, and is completely unrelated to `emailadres` instance field of `Account` class. The two pointers point to different places in memory.

If you want the instance of `Account` to have that data from `Login` instance, you have to give it to it somehow.

Comment: Hey I changed the code when I wrote it for the question. email_adres and pass_word are supposed to be emailadres and password. sorry for the mistake

Comment: Doesn't matter, they're still fields of different objects (even of different classes).